# How to add an image toward the right of a textbox and the text not overflowing to it

Tags: html, css, geolocation

I have the following textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="fromAdd" class="styledTB searchBDir" />
```

CSS:

```
.styledTB {
    padding-left: 5px;
    background: #E8E8E8;
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    right: 35px;
    box-shadow:
        0px 5px #BBB,
        0px 8px 10px rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.5);
}
.searchBDir {
    height: 30px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Displays this:

[image]

How can I add the following icon toward the right of the box and make it clickable for Geo Location:

[image]
[image]

To make something like this (I would like to resize the image to fit the textbox and not overlap as shown):

[image]

I am using the following script which will populate the textbox once the icon is clicked and the user gives permission:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("{textboxid}").text("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
}, "jsonp");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what we're doing

**Some slight changes to HTML**

```
<div class='styledTB'>
    <input type="textbox" id="gpsInput" />
    <button id="searchBDir"></button>
</div>
```

What we're doing here is giving some layout context for your input and button.  The container is going to serve as our bounding box for laying out the remainder of our elements.  You could accomplish this visually with only the input, but since you've got a clickable element it makes sense to make the clickable area a button (for accessibility, semantics, blah, blah, blah...).

**On to the CSS:**

```
.styledTB {
   position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;  /* Arbitrary number */
    width: 400px; /* Arbitrary number */    
}
.styledTB input {
    width: 100%; /* Arbitrary number */
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#searchBDir {
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px; /* Or however long you'd like your button to be, matches padding-right above */
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v62r.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Read the comments as they are helpful, but as a high-level overview:

We're putting the bounding box (the div) into a relative position so that we can order the button absolutely.  We define the size we want our input element to appear (I chose some number arbitrarily, it should work similarly no matter what size you set them to) and set display inline-block to mirror that of a normal `input` element.

We then force the box to fill its container with the `width` and `height` being declared as `100%` and give the box a `padding-right` of `40px` to match our intended size for the button.  We set the `box-sizing` to `border-box` so that the padding doesn't force the input larger than its containing box.  This just tells the browser to consider padding, borders and all internal spacing elements to not grow the outer bounds of the element.

Lastly, we set the button to `position: absolute` and give it the positioning values to force it to the right of the box.  We give it a background image of your GPS icon, and then position that appropriately within the button.

The `border` and `background-color` rules are there to override the default browser rendering of a button as a raised gray box.

I hope that helps!

## [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yfLntjd8/)

Comment: I will give it a go. I am not using fixed width to make it repsonsive but let me test it out. Thanks.

Comment: Check my edit.  That's got an attached fiddle and you could probably just steal it wholesale.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge – Also, those arbitrary numbers could be percentages just as easily.

Comment: Here is what I did http://jsfiddle.net/yfLntjd8/4/ ( The first textbox is the size that I have right now. Can you assist me with it. Thanks.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/yfLntjd8/6/ – You forgot to set `border-box` on the input, and I added `background-size:contain;` on the button.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Didn't notice you had put the styles on the elements themselves.  I'd highly recommend moving those to CSS, but here's an updated fiddle with them on the element: http://jsfiddle.net/yfLntjd8/10/

Comment: They are for testing purpose only. Always will use stylesheet! Thanks for the pointing out

Comment: Here is what I changed to: http://jsfiddle.net/yfLntjd8/11/ (Please help me make the third textbox the same width as the second textbox and also a bit more left and right padding for the image)

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - I don't mind helping, but if you're still having issues you might want to open another question.  If the original answer solved your problem, please accept it as your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Oooops... Yes u did help! Thanks. I accepted your answer. :)

Comment: Didn't even know there was a `calc`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

set the image as a background aligned to the right, and set the padding-right.

Comment: I will not be able to make it hot link where I can click on :/